# shape of my visual components form go mixed up when I run my project on other device with different resolution's screen

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

When I run my application on another PC the positions of components on the form is incorrect, for example my labels go off the edge of the Panel and TextBoxes overlap buttons.

My application is a Windows Forms application.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Typically the problem is that the other PC has a different (larger) system font size. Try resizing the fonts in the other PC and see if the problem goes away

Comment: You really need to provide more detail on what the problem is and what you have done already to try and fix it - also consider including a screenshot of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following could be the reasons for this

```
1. Screen Resolution
2. System Font Size
```

Comment: And the solution could be fixing the controls relative to the window, setting minimum window size, not using the default font size etc

Comment: Well just saying - since it was bound to be closed the OP could receive some hints :)